# pyspark(arrays_zip): remove key name from merged array

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

The pyspark dataframe contain 2 columns name "pk1" and "pk2" which are array of struct type:
[image]

[image]

I have used arrays_zip to merged above arrays and the output is:
[image]

I am expecting an output with out the key element after merging arrays, like:
[{"type": "savings", "email": "bimal@gmailcom","fixeddep_ac": "yes", "recurdep_ac": "yes"}]

Input Dataframe:
[image]

The code is:

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load(file_path).filter(col("customer").isNotNull())
df2 =  df1.withColumn("pk1",struct("type","email")).withColumn("pk2",struct("fixeddep_ac","recurdep_ac"))
df3 = df2.groupBy("customer","branch").agg(collect_set(col("pk1")).alias("pk1"),collect_set(col("pk2")).alias("pk2")).withColumn("pk2-pk4",arrays_zip(col("pk1"), col("pk2")))
display(df3)
```

The expected output column will be the merged of both array columns({1st element of pk1,1st element of pk2},{2nd element of pk1,2nd element of pk2}...).

How this can be achieved?

Comment: try [`zip_with`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.zip_with.html#pyspark-sql-functions-zip-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this as the input:

```
+---+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+  
|id |pk1                                             |pk2                    |
+---+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|1  |[{savings, a@gmail.com}, {savings, b@gmail.com}]|[{yes, yes}, {yes, no}]|
|2  |[{savings, c@gmail.com}, {savings, d@gmail.com}]|[{no, yes}, {no, no}]  |
+---+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

solution:

```
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('output', f.expr('transform(pk1, (x, i) -> struct(x.type, x.email, pk2[i].fixeddep_ac, pk2[i].recurdep_ac))'))
)
```

output:

```
+---+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |pk1                                             |pk2                    |output                                                             |
+---+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{savings, a@gmail.com}, {savings, b@gmail.com}]|[{yes, yes}, {yes, no}]|[{savings, a@gmail.com, yes, yes}, {savings, b@gmail.com, yes, no}]|
|2  |[{savings, c@gmail.com}, {savings, d@gmail.com}]|[{no, yes}, {no, no}]  |[{savings, c@gmail.com, no, yes}, {savings, d@gmail.com, no, no}]  |
+---+------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```